# Is this timesheet design (+ table structure) feasible in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, view

Part of an Access db I'm creating involves employees recording their time to sales bids and other activities.

Their time is represented in many ways:

- Could be actuals or forecasts.
- Time can be assigned to different tasks. These would be pulled from 2 separate tables (there are 2 categories of task). Categories are: Bid Work, and Management & Operations
- Normal view is a week at a time.
- Obviously, different employees do different things each day.
- Employees are to record whether they worked from home or not on a day (in actuals and forecasts)

So the way I imagined it is like this:

### tbl_Bids

- ID (PK)
- bid_name
- (loads more info on bid)

### tbl_MO_Activities

- ID (PK)
- activity_name

### tbl_Team_Members

- ID (PK)
- full_name
- etc.

### tbl_Timesheet_Days

- ID (PK)
- date
- team_member_idFK
- work_from_home (0 or -1)
- forecast (0 or -1)

### tbl_Timesheet_Hours

- ID (PK)
- timesheet_days_idFK
- activity_idFK (could be either from tbl_Bids or tbl_MO_Activities)
- activity_bid_yesno (0 or -1 and identifies which table the above field refers to)
- hours

So I think the table structure is Ok, it's getting Access to work with a decent view that is the difficulty. Basically, the ideal view would be something like the following:
http://i61.tinypic.com/358t9pf.png

My specific questions are: Can you get Access to represent the data in a tabular format (dates along the top, activities down the side), with the ability to add new activities (and hours spent on them in the days)? Will it require VBA (which I'm fine with)? Will this be very slow if VBA is used to populate each field?

Thanks